# How can I drop the procedure "create_synonym_db" in mysql?

Tags: mysql

It seems this procedure is de facto in the mysql 5.7
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-create-synonym-db.html

I've tried the `drop procedure create_synonym_db`, it does not seem to work; "procedure ... does not exist"

However, when I do a `show procedure status`, it's there.

I do not need it, did not create it, it's just clutter for me; any way to remove it?

Thanks!